# suppress printing "table of contents" or "contents" in latex

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I'm doing a custom document type with `article`. I'm using `titletoc`, `titlesec` and `tocloft`. Due to internal style guides, I need the titles "Contents", "List of Tables" and "List of Figures" to appear in a different style than the `\section` or `\section*` heading.

I think that the easiest way to do this is to simply suppress the "Contents," "List of Tables" and "List of Figures" text when `\tableofcontents` is run, and print it myself.

How do I suppress "Contents"?

Comment: \renewcommand{\contentsname}{} will suppress the text, but not the space used.

Comment: The `tocloft` docs also give instructions for styling the headers (sec. 2.2), if you want to do it that way. (I don't know if that conflicts with the other packages you use, though.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I need to suppress the generation of the \section*{}, because my \section's are white text on a black background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably one of the easiest ways to suppress printing the ToC/LoF/LoT headings would be to make `\section` gobble its arguments and just do nothing. That not only suppresses the heading, but also any space insertions (before and after).

One way of achieving this voiding of `\section` via a redefinition using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse), since it's easy to manage the starred version `\section*` which is typical of `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldsection\section
\newcommand{\voidsections}{\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{ s o m }{}}
\newcommand{\restoresections}{\let\section\oldsection}

\begin{document}

\voidsections% Totally remove functionality of \section
\tableofcontents
\restoresections% Restore \section functionality

\listoffigures

\voidsections% Totally remove functionality of \section
\listoftables
\restoresections% Restore \section functionality

\section{First section}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\section{Second section}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\section{Third section}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\section{Last section}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, `\voidsections` removes the functionality of `\section`, while `\restoresections` restores it. It should work with any package, assuming that you add the preamble content *after* loading your sectioning packages, as the structure remains fairly similar (they all use `\section*` for the ToC/LoF/LoT).

The example specifically nullifies the heading of the ToC and LoT, while still keeping other sectioning (LoF and the remainder of the document).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I am looking for.  I thought about redefining `\section*`, but didn't know how to stash the copy.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to select between multiple versions of `\section` (and `\section*`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldsection=\section

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\itshape}
\let\newsection=\section

\begin{document}
\let\section=\oldsection
\tableofcontents

\let\section=\newsection
\section{Demo}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]